# TextView as a Progress Bar in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-progressbar

I am trying to replicate the TextView as progress bar described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977626/textview-as-a-progressbar-with-textcolor-minipulation/14977840) using Kotlin, overriding the TextView class and using the canvas clipping trick in Zielony's comment.
The code *almost* works: I can see the text change color at the specified percentage (fixed, for now) but the background stays the same (yellow, the last background color I set).
Here's my code:

```
class ProgressTextView(context: Context): TextView(context) {
  override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    val color1 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryColor)
    val color2 = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.secondaryColor)
    var percent = 0.3 // Fixed progress % at 30%, for testing
    // first half
    canvas.save()
    setTextColor(Color.RED)
    setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
    canvas.clipRect(Rect(0, 0, (width * percent).toInt(), height))
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas.restore()
    // second half
    canvas.save()
    setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
    setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW)
    canvas.clipRect(Rect((width * percent).toInt(), 0, width, height))
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas.restore()
  }
}
```

What am I missing?
I managed to get it to work painting a rectangle instead of clipping for the first half, but I am still curious about how it should be done "properly", as this solution seems more elegant.

Comment: I would recommend that you not use that particular solution. Calling `setTextColor()` on a `TextView` causes it to invalidate, so you end up with an infinite redraw loop.

Comment: This is actually what happens (I naively thought it was ok). What would be the best approach here?